# ¿Cómo hago para permitir que más de un rol tenga acceso a una acción en un controlador?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Normalmente se coloca en un método de un controlador el rol que va a tener acceso al mismo:

`[Autorize(Roles="NombreRol")]`

**¿Cómo hago para darle permiso a más de un rol?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una forma de hacerlo es:

`[Authorize(Roles="NombreRol1, NombreRol2")]`

El crédito de esta respuesta es: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700166/allow-multiple-roles-to-access-controller-action/10723247#10723247

Otra podría ser usando Roles personalizados:

`[Authorize(Roles = CustomRoles.NombreRol1 +","+ CustomRoles.NombreRol2)]`

Donde la clase `CustomRoles` es:

```
public static class CustomRoles
{
    public const string NombreRol1 = "NombreRol1";
    public const string NombreRol2 = "NombreRol2";
}
```